# Execute command on linux terminal using subprocess in python

Tags: linux, python-2.7, mercurial

I want to execute following command on linux terminal using python script

```
hg log -r "((last(tag())):(first(last(tag(),2))))" work
```

This command give changesets between last two tags who have affected files in "work" directory

I tried:

```
import subprocess
releaseNotesFile = 'diff.txt'
with open(releaseNotesFile, 'w') as f:
    f.write(subprocess.call(['hg', 'log', '-r', '"((last(tag())):(first(last(tag(),2))))"', 'work']))
```

error:

```
abort: unknown revision '((last(tag())):(first(last(tag(),2))))'!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    f.write(subprocess.call(['hg', 'log', '-r', '"((last(tag())):(first(last(tag(),2))))"', 'work']))
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Working with os.popen()

```
with open(releaseNotesFile, 'w') as file:
    f = os.popen('hg log -r "((last(tag())):(first(last(tag(),2))))" work')
    file.write(f.read())
```

How to execute that command using subprocess ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem, change the `f.write(subprocess...` line to:

```
f.write(subprocess.call(['hg', 'log', '-r', '((last(tag())):(first(last(tag(),2))))', 'dcpp']))
```

#### Explanation

When calling a program from a command line (like bash), will "ignore" the `"` characters.  The two commands below are equivalent:

```
hg log -r something
hg "log" "-r" "something"
```

In your specific case, the original version in the shell has to be enclosed in double quotes  because it has parenthesis and those have a special meaning in bash.  In python that is not necessary since you are enclosing them using single quotes.

Comment: @rudm **Error** `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    f.write(subprocess.call(['hg', 'log', '-r', '((last(tag())):(first(last(tag(),2))))', 'work']))
TypeError: expected a character buffer object` output was printed on  terminal and empty file is created. But i want ouput in file

Comment: **Solved** 4th line should be `subprocess.call(['hg', 'log', '-r', '((last(tag())):(first(last(tag(),2))))', 'work'], stdout=f)`