# execute a linux command using python

Tags: python-2.7

Problem Statement:
A script to install packages in oracle linux 7 using python

Scenario:
I have a text file "oracle_package-requirement.txt" --> contains packages name 
i am using the following program to append that to list type variable using following code:

## !/usr/bin/env python

import os
f = open("/home/dipesh/oracle_package_requirement.txt","r")
myList = []
for line in f:
    myList.append(line)

## now i want to pass myList as input to yum -y install

So my question to the community is how can write this in my python code????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute command on linux terminal using subprocess in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240910/execute-command-on-linux-terminal-using-subprocess-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the subprocess module:

```
import os
import subprocess

f = open("/home/dipesh/oracle_package_requirement.txt","r")
myList = []
for line in f:
  myList.append(line.strip()) # strip to get rid of trailing newline
subprocess.check_call(['yum', '-y', 'install'] + myList)
```

Comment: @Mushir From commands module docs: "Deprecated since version 2.6: The commands module has been removed in Python 3. Use the subprocess module instead."